# problem using powerquery in excel to mimic a MINIFS formula

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table as below

```
match_id, minute, value
1, 1, 5
1, 2, 10
1, 3, 15
1, 4, -5
1, 5, -10
1, 6, -15
2, 1, 10
2, 2, 15
2, 3, 20
2, 4, -2
```

I am trying to replicate a =MINIFS formula in excel, I have added a custom column with a formula as below

`List.Min(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([match_id]=[match_id] and [value] <= 0))[value])`

However, ifs calculating the Min based on all of the records in the table rather than the ones that are filtered by .selectrows.

If I remove the list.min then it returns a list which does contain only the filtered rows but list.min still gives me the values for the entire table instead of just the filtered rows

Ive tried to find out why but Im not finding anything although I might be searching badly

Can anyone explain why it is doing that or Is there another way to mimic MINIFS within powerquery

expected results would be

```
match_id, minute, value, minifs
1, 1, 5, -15
1, 2, 10, -15
1, 3, 15, -15
1, 4, -5, -15
1, 5, -10, -15
1, 6, -15, -15
2, 1, 10, -2
2, 2, 15, -2
2, 3, 20, -2
2, 4, -2, -2
```

thanks

Comment: Please supply your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

- Group By `match_id` for the first part of the MINIFS equation.
- In the aggregation, calculate `List.Min` considering only the numbers with `Value <= 0`

  - If there are no values meeting the criteria, a *null* will be returned

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"match_id", Int64.Type}, {"minute", Int64.Type}, {"value", Int64.Type}}),

//Group for the "Value = Value" portion of your Excel MINIFS
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"match_id"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [match_id=nullable number, minute=nullable number, value=nullable number]},

    //calculate List.Min on only the negative numbers
    //Will return "null" if there are no 0 or negative numbers
        {"MINIFS", (t)=>List.Min(List.Transform(t[value], each if _ <= 0 then _ else null)), type nullable number}}),

    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"minute", "value"}, {"minute", "value"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

If you want to use a different function on the filtered table, replace, for example `List.Min` with `List.Average` or whatever.

[image]

---

*By the way, if you wanted to do this using the `Add Column` method, a correct syntax would be:*

```
    #"Added Custom" = 
        Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "MINIFS", 
            (c)=>
                List.Min(
                    Table.Column(
                        Table.SelectRows(
                            #"Changed Type", each [match_id] = c[match_id] and [value] <=0),
                    "value")
                )
            )
```

*In my opinion, I believe the `Table.Group` method would be more efficient in part because you would only be executing the `Table.SelectRows` and `List.Min` methods once for each `match_id` instead for every row in the database*

Answer (score 0):

Group as follows and then expand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, it also needs to check for [value] <= 0 (required on the full data set and for other AVERAGEIFS calculations etc). Im not sure grouping would allow me to do that

Comment: I don't follow. This works with your sample data and expected results. If you have different sample data and different expected results, you should post those.

Comment: Filter your data to [value] <= 0 first, then do the grouping. Or, add a conditional column like "MIN_value" = If [value] is greater than 0 then 0 else [value]. Then do the grouping on that new column.